# fail2ban expired bans not removed from iptables

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I have recently installed fail2ban on Ubuntu 16, and it's working in that bans/assignments to jails is working correctly, but once the jail assignment expires, the banned IP remains in iptables as REJECT. I would expect it to remove from iptables after the bantime expires.

Example below, a very basic DOS jail, bans anyone who hits 100 page loads in 30 seconds, banning them for 1 hour (3600 seconds).

NB the default bantime in jail.conf is 600 seconds

**jail.local**

```
 [http-get-dos]
 enabled = true
 port = http,https
 filter = http-get-dos
 logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log
       /home/*/logs/access.log
 maxretry = 100
 findtime = 30
 bantime = 3600
 ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ::1
 action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

**filter.d/http-get-dos**

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
ignoreregex =
```

I tested this myself by sending 1000 connections from three other servers, and it worked correctly - all three servers were added into the jail, and iptables rule:

**iptables -L -n**

```
Chain f2b-HTTP (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  xx.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with 
REJECT     all  --  xx.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with 
REJECT     all  --  xx.xx.xx.xx         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with 
icmp-port-unreachable
```

However, it's been about 2 hours and the three REJECTs still exists in the iptables and the servers cannot connect.

A live status on the http-get-dos jail (fail2ban-client status http-get-dos) returns that correctly some IPs **were** banned, but none currently.

```
Status for the jail: http-get-dos
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     613
|  `- File list:        /var/log/apache2/access.log /home/*/logs/access.log 
`- Actions
|- Currently banned: 0
|- Total banned:     3
`- Banned IP list:
```

At install of fail2ban, I ran:

```
 apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

To persist bans on reboot, but this doesn't (??) ignore the bantime though.

I know I can manually remove an IP from iptables, but I would expect fail2ban to do it automatically after the bantime has expired.

What am I missing?